# Rails validation specific for one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm working on a web-application, where user has a two-step signup process. After the first step the User object is already created. And in second step, User will fill in more information. Hence, I am wondering how I can create form-specifc validation. I have copied my relevant code here.

**Controller** after_sign_up_controller.rb:

```
class Users::AfterSignupController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    # after_save :user_signup_completed!    

    def finish
        verify_referral_code params[:referer_referral_code]

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render }
            format.json { render :json => { errors: resource.errors }, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end

    protected

    def form_params
        params.permit(
            :referer_referral_code,
            :primary_email,
            :mobile_number,
            :nickname,
            :date_of_birth
        )
    end

end
```

I am thinking of using validator to validate the params in this form. But I am not too sure how to do it.

I have created `app/validators/after_sign_up_validator.rb`

```
class AfterSignUpValidator < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActiveModel::Validations

    attr_accessor :referer_referral_code, :primary_email, :date_of_birth, :mobile_number, :nickname

    validate :referer_referral_code, :validates_referral_code
    validate :mobile_number, presence: true, numericality: {only_integer: true}
    validate :primary_email, :validates_email
    validates_presence_of :date_of_birth
    validates_presence_of :nickname

    def validates_email email
        if current_user.email == email
            return true
        end
        if User.where(email: email).nil?
            errors.add(:email, 'Email already exists')
        end
    end

    def validates_referral_code refcode
        if refcode != ""
            u = User.where(referral_code: refcode).first
            if u.nil?
                errors.add(:referer_referral_code, 'No such referral code')
            end

            if !u.nil? && u.id
                return u.id
            end
        end
    end

end
```

I have some logics available, but I don't know how to wire the validators specifically to this form.

Since `AfterSignUpValidator` is part of `User` Model but itself is not a model.. I don't really know where it should inherit from.

Any guidance is appreciated~!

Answer (score 3):

A common approach in these types of situations is to extract this functionality into form objects. [This blog post](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) has a good rundown on form objects using the [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) gem which works really well.

There is also [Reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform) which looks promising although I haven't had a chance to use it.

Finally, if you have a Railscasts Pro account (highly recommended), Ryan did a great episode on [form objects](http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes for simple use cases you can define context validations.

It looks like:

```
# in model
validates :referal_code, on: :signup.
validates :email, on: :update.

# in controller 
@user = User.new(user_params)
if user.save(:signup)
...
```

More info in [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F) or [blog article](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/09/15/a-lightweight-way-to-handle-different-validation-situations/).